# reference for lexicographic path ordering

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, partial-order, automated-theorem-proving, term-rewriting-systems

Can you recommend a good reference for reading about lexicographic/recursive path orderings?

I'm currently reading about lpo's in Chapter 2 of the Handbook of Automated Reasoning, 'Resolution Theorem Proving' by Bachmair and Ganzinger, but the presentation is really terse. I would ideally like a more tutorial-like introduction w/ examples.

Answer (score 8):

Some information at the right level of abstraction can be found in:

- Nachum Dershowitz's [A Taste of Rewrite Systems](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~fleck/181content/taste-fixed.pdf)

If you are near a library or bookshop, this book has even more details:

- Baader and Nipkov's [Term Rewriting and All That](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521779200)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I've read the section on orders from 'Term Rewriting and All That' and it was very good and quite easy to follow.